# IIS: how to write a match url which is captured only once

Tags: c#, .net, redirect, iis

I need to redirect URLs like the following:

```
http://www.ourserver.it/pictures/17693112-811322.jpg
```

The redirect depends on whether the picture has already been put in a subdirectory or not. If so it must be redirected to:

```
http://www.ourserver.it/ApplicationName/pictures/year/month/day/17693112-811322.jpg
```

otherwise if it has not been put yet in a new location in the file system, I need to redirect here

```
http://www.ourserver.it/ApplicationName/pictures/17693112-811322.jpg
```

So, this is the rule in IIS

```
<rules>
  <rule name="DbProviderTest" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(pictures/([0-9]+)-([0-9]+).jpg)" />
    <conditions>
      <add input="{DBLORY:{R:1}}" pattern="(.+)" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}" />
  </rule>
</rules>
```

And this the store procedure in the SQL Server which should give the new location:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetRewrittenUrl] 
@input nvarchar(256)
AS

declare @redirection nvarchar(256)

SELECT @redirection = rt.NewUrl 
FROM RewriteDB.dbo.RewriteTable rt 
WHERE rt.OriginalUrl = @input

if @redirection is null or @redirection = ''
select 'Omniservice/'+@input
else
select @redirection
```

where `Omniservice` is the name of our web application. As you can see, if there's not a new location for the picture yet, it simply returns the old url concatenated to the application name. Therefore, if the picture has been put in a new location it works fine. Otherwise I have a loop to `http://www.omniservice.it/ApplicationName/pictures/17693112-811322.jpg` saying

> TOO MANY REDIRECTS.

because it keeps on being captured by the rule.

How can I avoid this? I have tried with:

```
<match url="www.ourserver.it/(pictures/([0-9]+)-([0-9]+).jpg)" />
```

where I've explicitly written the application name should not be contained in the original url but even if IIS 8 says it's ok and matches the rule, then nothing happens on the browser and nothing is redirected.
Which is the correct syntax?

**UPDATE**

Maybe, might using `^` make it work? Something like the following:

```
<match url="(^pictures/([0-9]+)-([0-9]+).jpg)" />
```

Or maybe, is

```
<match url="^(pictures/([0-9]+)-([0-9]+).jpg)" />
```

the correct one?

Because according to documentation `^` is used to capture something which starts with a certain sequence of character. In my case the URL to redirect (the part after the host name) should start with `pictures/` while the new would start with `ApplicationName/pictures/` and so it should not be captured anymore.

**UPDATE 2**

So, maybe I was right and this could be the final working solution:

```
<match url="^(pictures/([0-9]+)-([0-9]+).jpg)" />
```

This way, the first request is splitted into the following capture group R:1 `pictures/17693112-811322.jpg` which, since it begins with the word `pictures` and since it hasn't still be placed into a newer position in the file system, is simply redirected to `ApplicationName/pictures/17693112-811322.jpg`. This last does not begin with the word `pictures` and so the loop is avoided and at last the file is showed.

All this damned mess is caused because the developers which worked to this project before me thought, for some unknown reason, that the customer had to see and save in SAP `http://www.ourserver.it/pictures/17693112-811322.jpg` as url to access the file and not the real URL `http://www.ourserver.it/ApplicationName/pictures/17693112-811322.jpg`, also because the files physically have always resided in `D:\inetpub\wwwroot\ApplicationName\pictures\`, which is the path where the web application is installed in IIS.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no syntax that will work with URL Rewrite. You are basically saying "if the file doesn't exist on disk, do A; otherwise do B". URL Rewrite doesn't check files on disk. You have 2 choices: 1) Make a custom HTTP Module to do the redirect 2) Use ASP.NET (or MVC) to do it by routing all `*.jpg` files there in web.config. Either way, you should **not** check the disk on a per-request basis - you should cache the `.GetHashCode()` of the file names and check the `GetHashCode()` of the incoming URL against the cache in order to determine if the file exists on disk.

Comment: I'm afraid you have misunderstood me. I don't want URL Rewrite to check if a file exists or not in the disk. The file will surely exist. I just want it to behave differently according to the result of a stored procedure in SQL server which does know where the file actually is. So the stored procedure could return either `applicationName/pictures/file.jpg` or `applicationName/pictures/year/month/day/file.jpg` in any case. I simply want the request to be redirected to this result without being captured again ending in a loop. That's all